# Zen Python: должен быть только один путь сделать это

Tags: python

День!
Мой вопрос скорее методический. Захотелось вернуться в преподавание программирования на взрослом уровне. Для этого везде решаю простенькие задачки в поисках жемчуга. [Здесь](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-nested-logic/problem) есть задачка о вложенных `if`.  Вкратце суть такая.
Если книжку вернули в библиотеку на год+ позже, то штраф 10000. Если год вовремя но месяц с опозданием 500 за каждый месяц. Если же опоздали на несколько дней то штраф 15 за каждый день. Ну не суть.
Вот решил эту задачку тремя способами. какой из них тот "единственный" который по-настоящему пайтоновский.
***import this*** содержит:
 ***There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it***
Вопрос задаю не ради флуда, но ради мнения людей, которые решели более взрослые задачи чем эта и могут дать мудрый совет, который будет полезен моим будущим ученикам.
Итак. 1 - способ решения через `if`:

```
date = []

for i in range(2):
    date.append([ x for x in map(int,input().split(" "))])
# in 1st row - actually date, in2-nd excepted date
# elements mapping: 0: day, 1:month, 2:year
if date[0][2] - date[1][2] <0:  # 1 year before
    result = 0
else:
    month_diff = date[0][1] - date[1][1]
    days_diff = date[0][0] - date[1][0]
    if date[0][2] - date[1][2] >0:
        result = 10000
    elif month_diff>0: #wrong month
        result = 500*month_diff
    elif days_diff>0:  #wrong day
        result = 15*days_diff
    else:
        result = 0
print(result)
```

Способ 2: вся логика осталась в *списке списков списков* функций. То есть `if` практически нет!

```
date = []
for i in range(2):
    date.append([ x for x in map(int,input().split(" "))])
# in 1st row - actually date, in2-nd excepted date
# elements mapping: 0: day, 1:month, 2:year

def sign_plus(diff):
    return 0 if diff<0 else 1 if diff==0 else 2


def month_penalty(days_diff, month_diff, years_diff):
    return 500*month_diff

def day_penalty(days_diff, month_diff, years_diff):
    return 15*days_diff

def year_penalty(days_diff, month_diff, years_diff):
    return 10000

def all_in_time(days_diff, month_diff, years_diff):
    return 0


list_no_if = [[[all_in_time for i in (0,1,2)] for j in (0,1,2)] for k in (0,1,2)]    
##
# level k==0: "year before time"; level k==1: "just in time";  k==2: "later"     
for i in (0,1,2):
    for j in (0,1,2):
        list_no_if[i][j][2] = year_penalty
# j - is responceble for month
for i in (0,1,2):
     list_no_if[i][2][1] = month_penalty

# i  - for days
list_no_if[2][1][1] = day_penalty

years_diff = date[0][2] - date[1][2]
month_diff = date[0][1] - date[1][1]
days_diff = date[0][0] - date[1][0]

print(list_no_if[sign_plus(days_diff)][sign_plus(month_diff)][sign_plus(years_diff)](days_diff, 
                 month_diff, years_diff) )
```

глаза можно сломать. Но когда логика супер сложная - вариант возможен.

Третий вариант - "срединный путь", где часть `if`-ов исчезает благодаря силе `return`, а использование словаря позволяет уменьшить острую необходимость многословных комментариев. Мне этот вариант и самому больше нравится. Но дкмаю, нужны более серьезные аргументы чем "нравится - не нравится"

```
date = {'actually':{}, 'expected':{}}
for key in date.keys():
    date[key]['day'], date[key]['month'], date[key]['year'] = map(int,input().split(" "))

def hack_points(days_diff, month_diff, years_diff):
    if years_diff<0: return 0
    if years_diff>0: return 10000
    if month_diff>0: return 500*month_diff
    if days_diff>0:  return 15*days_diff
    return 0

print( hack_points(
                date["actually"]["day"] - date["expected"]["day"],
                date["actually"]["month"] - date["expected"]["month"],
                date["actually"]["year"] - date["expected"]["year"],
                )
    )
```

и да. На вход подоется нечто подобное:

```
9 6 2015
6 6 2015
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, как вы хотите считать дельту по времени. `01.01.2019 - 31.12.2018 = 1 год` и штраф 10000?

Comment: @mkkik не я писал условие задачи))  Дельту по времени считать не просили. Да. Принес не в тот год - штраф 10000. Мож у них в новогоднюю ночь инвентарицация и за каждую книгу надо заплатить 10000 даже если потом книга вернется. Не суть.
Все три решения сайт принял и за любое из них дадут очки. Если абстрагироваться от того что задача именно на "ифы" - какое решение то ЕДИНСТВЕННОЕ?

Comment: "На вкус и цвет все фломастеры разные", в смысле разным людям могут понравиться различные варианты...

Comment: Какое из правил (`import this`) нарушено?

Comment: Но @MaxU!  возможно я чрезмерно искренне воспринимаю ZEN Python, но при таком подходе этот пункт ZEN Python просто зря занимает место ))
Задам тот же вопрос по-другому. Где в жизни применялся хоть раз этот пункт?

Comment: @MaxU
  There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.